# JavaScript RegExp replace multiple strings with multiple other strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an autocomplete (jQuery) in which I want to highlight any words in the dropdown that occur in the user input. User enters: "holy water" then both holy and water should be highlighted even if they're not next to each other. So entering multiple words should highlight multiple words if present

[image: Entering multiple words should highlight multiple words if present]

I'm trying to do this with just making text bold using a regular expression

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
    var termWords = this.term.trim().split(" ").join("|"); //if multiple words, split into parts, join back with ors to use in regexp
    var regex = new RegExp("({"+termWords+"[s]?}*)([\s\.,])","gi"); // convert to regex, make global and case insensitive
    var currentLabel = item.label;
    var currentLabel = currentLabel.replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>$2");
    var itemHtml = '<a>'+ currentLabel + '</a>';
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .html(itemHtml)
        .appendTo( ul );
}
```

Trying this out if I enter "is language", the output expression becomes

```
/({is|language[s]?}*)([s.,])/gi
```

But the problem is, none of the text I enter matches and hence isn't highlighted.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I'm trying: http://jsfiddle.net/8tD49/5/ , just note that it's not exactly the same as my own ajax function returns results as seen in the image.

**Edit:**

Final answer to highlight multiple strings:

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
    var termWords = this.term.trim().split(" ").join("|"); //if multiple words, split into parts, join back with ors
    "(?:"+termWords+"[s]?)*"
    var regex = new RegExp("((?:"+termWords+")s?)([\s.,])?","gi");
    var currentLabel = item.label;
    var currentLabel = currentLabel.replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>$2");
    var itemHtml = '<a>'+ currentLabel + '</a>';
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .html(itemHtml)
        .appendTo( ul );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8tD49/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mixed up `{}` and simple parenthesis. For matching either something OR another, the syntax is `something|other`. If you need to enclose in non-selective parenthesis, the syntax is

```
(?:is|language[s]?)*
```

But here, I don't think the `*` is necessary. You want to match all occurrences of a few words: all you have to do is do a regex that would match any of these words. The `g` flag will take care of repeating the task.

Your complete regex should then become:

```
"/((?:"+termWords+")s?)([\s.,])?/gi"
...
/((?:is|language)s?))([s.,])?/gi
```

The `([.,]?)` part (why did you put an s there, btw?) seems a little restrictive too. You could use `(\W?)` instead for english language (`\W` is short for non alphanumerical character, ie `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`, which means it would catch any punctuation but mess up words like `journée`).

And you may wanna be careful when you try to catch plural, in this example `iss` would also be catched... This part probably needs a bit more thinking !

Comment: Edited answer for a few more precautions you might wanna take.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use word boundaries (\b)

(\bis\b|\blanguage\b)

is this the correct language.  The above regex matches **is** and **language**.

Comment: well, i do want to bold a substring, not entire words

Comment: for example I still want to highlight brook even though I didn't type brookstone

Comment: Ahh, yes.  I was mainly basing it off of your 1st paragraph description. It'll be interesting.  Say the first character typed is an "a", you could get a lot of highlighed a's.